# Ionic 4 - authService returns no value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am very new to Ionic and Angular. I am following a tutorial where Ionic 2 is used but, I am using Ionic 4 I guess i.e, I use `HttpClient` module instead of `Http` module and so on.

I am creating a signup page. When I try to fill all the credentials and press the signup button. Nothing Happens. When I view my `console.log`, it shows me `Connection Failed`, which is erring part of my **signup.ts**

Please help to resolve this issue.

Here is my code:

**signup.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="userData.password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button full color="secondary" (click)="signup()">Sign Up</button>
```

**signup.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from './../../providers/auth- 
service/auth-service';
import { TabsPage } from './../tabs/tabs';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})
export class SignupPage {
  responseData: any;
  userData = {"username":"", "password":"", "email":"", "name":""};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams, public authService: AuthServiceProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPage');
  }

  signup(){
    //api Connections
    this.authService.postData(this.userData, "signup").then((result) => 
{
      this.responseData = result;
      console.log(this.responseData);
     // localStorage.setItem('userData', 
JSON.stringify(this.responseData))
      this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
    }, (err)=>{
      console.log("Connection Failed");
    });
  }

}
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

let apiUrl ="http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/";


@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }


  postData(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();

      this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), 
{headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res=>{
        resolve(res);
      }, (err)=>{
        reject(err);
      });
    });

  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic- 
angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth- 
service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { SignupPage } from './../pages/signup/signup';
import { LoginPage } from './../pages/login/login';
import { WelcomePage } from './../pages/welcome/welcome';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    WelcomePage,
    LoginPage,
    SignupPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    WelcomePage,
    LoginPage,
    SignupPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen, AuthServiceProvider,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: please include the console output

Comment: Try printing the error which came from the `Promise` so that we can diagnose more. `console.log("Connection Failed", err);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added console.log("Connection Failed", err); and here is the console response, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFsWW.png

Comment: I have noted that sometimes my database is updating properly with the credentials I enter in the signup page.

Comment: Thank you. I have found out the problem. The problem was with API file in the server. Now its working nice.